# Rails 4 render Gritter messages in js view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, gritter

Using Rails 4.2.4, ruby 2.2.2, [gritter gem 1.2.0](https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter). My controller respond with js:

```
#posts_controller.rb
if @post.update post_params
  gflash :success => "Link updated"
end
```

in accordion with [official doc](https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter#gflash) this is my js view:

```
#update.js.erb
<%= gflash :js => true %>
```

The problem is none is rendered, Rails server works fine and no problems are show in console. I have inspected the produced js and I have see this:

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery.gritter.add({image:'/assets/success-0b8a2dedd729f28e513472812f5483ae2817ae482c0b744c3ce56c9dd2b2bc1d.png',title:'
Success',text:'Link updated'});});
```

It seems the browser doesn't render the jQuery function. (I have jquery allready installed in my app)
Ideas?

Comment: Check out jQuery and jQuery.gritter inside a browser console.

Comment: Sorry, what is the procedure to checkout?

Comment: in the Chrome console it works fine. I have no  idea

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

*Short:* `<%= (gflash :js => true).html_safe %>`

*Long:* Inspecting server response with Fiddler Web Debugger I have notice the response is like this:

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery.gritter.add({image:&#39;/assets/success-0b8a2dedd729f28e513472812f5483ae2817ae482c0b744c3ce56c9dd2b2bc1d.png&#39;,title:&#39;Success&#39;,text:&#39;Link updated&#39;});});
```

If I execute the code above in chrome console I have an error:

```
VM8474:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

So using the `html_safe` method works for me: `<%= (gflash :js => true).html_safe %>`